# Can you remove specific graphs in a survey's graphical summary?

Tags: survey-list

I have a survey, and it works okay, but the graphical summary is flat out dumb. Most of the questions are "rating" questions where you rate 1-5. That works fine, but there are also a few multiline questions for comments and questions that simply could not be answered in the rating form.

In the graphical summary, I don't want the multiline questions to show up since every single answer ever gets its own bar and looks bad and clogs up the summary with useless information that I don't need to analyze in that way. If it isn't possible just let me know and I will just have to find an alternate option outside of SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (as most user interface tweaks are) with [jQuery](http://jquery.com). The way to add SharePoint to your page depends partly on your version of SharePoint so you will need to search for that (or ask here on the site).

Once you have it deployed there is a [tutorial on hiding specific elements](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aBasic_Show_and_Hide). The only tricky thing will be getting your selectors right.